# Can the --prefix path be the same as the directory where I downloaded/unzipped the source?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiling, configure, r

I was trying to build R myself and put it in a `temp_R` folder by giving a command like `./configure --prefix=/dir/where/I/wanted/to/put/R`. But it seems that some of the important stuff was put into the temp_R folder all the same.

Should I have extracted the archive to the folder where I wanted to have R before compiling, or what other solution should I use?

Comment: Building R from source should not be necessary except under special circumstances, say you want to build a custom version. If you want backports, try the R Debian packages built built by Dirk. They should work on Ubuntu. Alternatively, you could backport Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `./configure --prefix ...` it typically puts all the files in the directory you just downloaded to anyway. The `--prefix` option is utilized during the `make` and `make install` steps that you run afterwards.

Primarily the `make install` step will install all the software that the `make` step compiled to the locations derived from `--prefix /some/path`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should have extracted to folder you wanted the files in, before compiling.  The compiler just puts the files where the archive was extracted if no specific destination was given.